# Energy lost as heat and sliding friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

The answer to this problem is given at the back of the book as 5.0 J. The book is for olympiad preparation (from india).I borrowed it from a friend.Its name is 'pathfinder by arvind tiwari and sachin singh'.

I believe I'm making some conceptual errors in the problem.my answers range from 15.5 J to 5.75 J but they are all incorrect.

1.Firstly,I can't understand how 17.5 J worth of (min )work can be done without significantly sliding the box, even after the bar is completely on the frictional plane.Am I right in assuming that the bar would slide even after it's completely on the plane ?

2.Also, will energy lost as heat,only appear via sliding frictional work on the bar or are there other ways too for the heat to be lost here ?

3.Does'minimum work' mean zero kinetic energy changes in the bar are to be assumed and that's it? All forces balance out all the time.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fun exercise! One point besides the good hints given in the answer by Bob D: do you take the friction force as being proportional to the length of the bar that is actually in contact with the floor causing friction? Indeed as the contact surface increases, the overall resulting friction force should increase.

Comment: @user8736288 Actually the friction force does not depend on the contact area because, for a fixed normal force (weight) the pressure between the contacting surfaces (force per unit area) is reduced when the area increases. This cancels the effect of the amount of friction area. That’s why area is never included in friction force equations.

Comment: @Bob D the total weight in contact with friction (total normal force) increases as the rod is pulled

Comment: @user8736288 Valid point. In this particular scenario the pressure is constant but the area increases as the bar is pulled, ergo the force increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

1. The bar slides the length $l$ and stops. This can be achieved by dragging it very slowly with the pulling force exactly equal to the friction force.
2. The only energy lost as heat is the kinetic friction work which equals the kinetic friction force times the length of the bar.
3. The minimum work means there is no overall change in kinetic energy of the bar. That’s the case if the bar begins at rest and ends at rest. Then per the work energy theorem the net work done on the bar moving it on the friction surface is zero. The negative work done by friction equals the positive work done by the pulling force. Yes, all forces balance out all of the time.

From here you should be able to calculate the friction work knowing the total work equals the friction work plus the energy stored in the spring. Keep in mind that the friction force is not constant because the weight of the bar is not fully supported by the friction surface until fully on top. It varies linearly up to that point. The energy stored in the spring is based upon the maximum friction force.

Hope this helps

Comment: Bob D-hey :) i used your method of assuming that the friction as soon as the bar starts sliding is µmg and first the spring will have to balance that for motion to start..during this phase the spring is being stretched only  potential energy is being accumulated by it..let us this call this potential energy as W1 =(1/2) k x^2 where x is extension of the spring....now in the 2nd phase the bar starts sliding as soon as µmg =kx and during this phase,the work done by the external force balances work done by friction i.e W 2 =kx*L where L is length of the bar that slides which is 1.0 metre..

Comment: @QiLin Xue -hey mind having a look ? :)

Comment: @Amy.fosters1729 As user8736288 pointed out above, the friction force is not constant while sliding the bar onto the friction surface. It's a linear function of the distance the bar travels over the friction surface.

Comment: @Amy.fosters1729I’m afraid so.  I believe friction is independent of the surface area based on the assumption that the normal force $N$ is totally supported by the surface having friction. That’s the case in most of the friction example problems. In this case, however, it is not.

Comment: For example, when the bar is half way onto the friction surface, the force supported by the friction surface is only half the weight of the bar. You can’t count the half of the weight that is supported by the frictionless surface when you apply the equation. So with the bar half way onto the surface the friction force is actually $μ_{k}N/2$ and not $μ_{k}N$.

Comment: i think i'll just give up this problem..i solved according to the varying friction approach (where work done by friction would equal μmgL/2 for sliding a length L(  using basic calculus) and i got the answer for heat evolved i.e μmgL/2  itself as 1.09 J..:(

Comment: @Amy.fosters1729 I'm  still thinking about it because it is an interesting problem. I originally got the same quadratic function as you did with the same 8.85 J result before realizing I can't use a constant friction force. If I come up with something, I'll share it with you.

Comment: @Amy.Fosters 1729 if you apply my revision to the last paragraph you will get the book answer. I did

Comment: @ Bob D : ) Okay..let me check.ill get back.this maybe the 10th time that I will try to solve this problem : )

Comment: @Amy.fosters1729 OK. I'd like to know what you get.

Comment: -hey..finally solved it..i was doing a bad mistake in my quadratic,,taking the heat lost as negative again and again,,finally got 5 J..thank you :):)

Comment: @Amy.fosters 1729 Great. Glad I could help

Comment: hey thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Amy.fosters 1729 So, was my answer acceptable?

Comment: yes..the friction was to be increased gradually and and won't be a constant..also i was wrongly taking the heat loss as negative in the quadratic.it has to be positive as it is included in the work done by external agency..after correcting for that..the answer came out as 5 J.

Comment: @Amy.fosters1729 OK I was just wondering since you hadn't formally "accepted" my answer.

Comment: haha..how do i formally accept ?,is this related to the reputation points on this forum ? if it is.please let me know..:)

Comment: @Amy.fosters 1729 next to each answer there’s an “accept” button